# React state arrays are changing/being sorted together when only one array is called to be changed/sorted

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays in my state, one is randomly generated and I want the other to be the sorted version of the random array. Every time I call my sort function on my second array they always both change! Does anyone know why this is? I'm pulling my hair out over this...

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      array: Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)),
      sortedArray: [],
     };

    this.generateArray = this.generateArray.bind(this);
  };

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.generateArray}>Generate Array</button>
      </div>
    );
  }

generateArray(e) {

    let a = this.state.array;
    this.setState({ sortedArray: a.sort() });
}
```

When I call this function in my render method, both the state.array and state.sortedArray change to be sorted, how do I only sort one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array.prototype.sort()` method in JavaScript sorts the array in-place; in other words, it changes the original array. Putting a `slice()` in front of `sort()` to make a shallow copy of the array will fix the problem: `a.slice().sort()`